# Why bash color encoding doesn't need terminating character?

Tags: bash

`green="\033[0;32m"` Where `\033` is the escape character and `\003[` starts an escape sequence. However why doesn't it need a terminating character such as `\]`

I read `\]` is required to terminate the escape sequence
https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html

Comment: `why doesn't it need a terminating character such as \]` Why does it need? It already ends with `m`. (Also, no, `"\033"` is a string with  4 characters slash and three digits. Probably you are later using `echo -e` or `printf` that converts that 4 character string a single `0o33` byte)

Comment: `\]` is required at the end of a non-printing sequence in a prompt string, which has to be in `\[...\]` so the shell knows how wide the prompt really is (see [manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Controlling-the-Prompt)).

Comment: @KamilCuk. I think `\033` is interpreted as a single byte by bash.

Comment: Try `echo "\033"` is 4 characters. Bash when _displaying_ `PS1` variable content _replaces_ the string `\033` by one byte it's hex counterpart, as explained in the link you posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why bash color encoding doesn't need terminating character?

It needs one and has one - the terminating character is `m`.

> why doesn't it need a terminating character such as ]

Because a character, in this case character `m`, is used to detect the end of ansi escape sequence.

For more information read [wikipedia ansi escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) and [ECMA-35 around section 13](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-035.pdf) and [ECMA-48 section 5](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-048.pdf).

> I read ] is required to terminate the escape sequence

The `\[` and `\]` are used to notify **bash** that a prompt it uses has an ansi escape sequence **inside** if it, so that when **bash** calculates the length of line with the prompt it doesn't make mistakes.

It's used like:

```
 PS1="\[\033[0;32m\]something "
      ^^          ^^ - bash ignores what is inside to calculate visible length
        ^^^^^^^^^^   - ansi escape seuqnece
```

Comment: What do you mean visible length? `echo -e "\[word\]"` still outputs the visible word.

Comment: But bash when calculating the count of columns used to display `\[word\]` would count zero. This information is used to correctly calculate line breaks on long commands, for example when clicking ↑ up arrow key and displaying a long previous command. Without `\[..\]` and with ansi escape sequences the line breaks will be in incorrect places. Also `\[` and `\]` are ignored by `echo -e` and taken literally.